# Does client-side code that calls an an async function need to use await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

Imagine the following hypothetical, minimal implementation of a function that does a simple HTTP GET request using axios. This uses `await/async` as depicted in the post.

```
const axios = require('axios')

exports.getStatus = async id => {
  const resp = await axios.get(
    `https://api.example.com/status/${id}`
  )

  return resp
}
```

Is the promise not resolved using `await`? Is it required that the client uses `await` as depicted below? Is it safe to assume that anytime a client consumes an async function, that it also needs to use `await` when calling the function?

```
// client
const { getStatus } = require('./status')

const response = await getStatus(4)
```

Comment: All `async` functions use an implicit Promise to return their result. *"Is it safe to assume that anytime a client consumes an async function, that it also needs to use await when calling the function?"* - Correct, assuming you're dependent on the result. You must handle the result as a Promise, whether that be by using `await` or callbacks like `.then(...)`. [More information](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)...

Comment: @TylerRoper That's where I'm confused. Isn't the Promise resolved by the `await` declaration when invoking `axios.get(...)`? why would the consuming code need to resolve it also?

Comment: You have two promises here: the one returned by `axios.get` (which is resolved by `await`), and the one returned by `exports.getStatus`. Perhaps a poor analogy, but imagine you called me and said "Call the local market and find out if they have bread.". So I call them, and I wait for their answer. But *you* still have to wait for *me* to give you an answer, right? *Or*, I can call you back (a "callback").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer, no.
Labelling a function `async` means 2 things:

1) you're allowed to use `await` inside the function.

2) The function returns a `promise`; i.e. you *can* use await on its return value, or you can use `.then`, or `Promise.all`, or even ignore the return value, or anything else you can do with promises.

E.g. you could do the following which (depending on your use case) could be more performant because it needs not wait for the response to continue.

```
// client
const { getStatus } = require('./status')

const response4 = getStatus(4);
const response5 = getStatus(5);

// do stuff that don't rely on the responses.

response4.then(response => myOutput.setFirstOutput(response));
response5.then(response => myOutput.setSecondOutput(response));
```

Btw, your first snippet is redundant with its usage of `await`; it's equivalent to

```
const axios = require('axios')

exports.getStatus = id =>
  axios.get(`https://api.example.com/status/${id}`);
```

This is because `return await promise` is equivalent to `return promise`, both return the same promise. There is one exception regarding rejected promises. Awaiting a rejected promise will throw an exception (which you can catch with a `try/catch` block), whereas directly returning a rejected promise will not throw an exception but you should still handle the rejection (with a `.catch` clause). To illustrate:

```js
let promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve('resolved after 2 seconds'), 2000));

let returnPromise = () => promise;
let returnAwaitPromise = async () => await promise;

returnPromise().then(value => console.log('returnPromise,', value));
returnAwaitPromise().then(value => console.log('returnAwaitPromise,', value));
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Is it redundant because `axios.get()` returns a Promise?

Comment: I can't seem to edit my first comment, but if you get a moment, I'd love to understand why my usage of await is redundant.

Comment: added explanation

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to use await. An async function returns a Promise that should be resolved. Instead of using await, you can simply call `.then()` like so:

```
// client
const { getStatus } = require('./status');

getStatus(4).then((response) => {
    //Do something with the response
}).catch((error) => {
    //Handle possible exceptions
});
```

Below I'll address your question from the comments. The `getStatus` function could be rewritten like this:

```
exports.getStatus = (id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(`https://api.example.com/status/${id}`).then((resp) => {
            resolve(resp);
        }).catch((error) => {
            reject(error);
        })
    });
}
```

It would act **exactly** the same as in your version. When you call asynchronous functions in series, you have to resolve each of the returned Promises. In your case, there are two of them - the one returned by `axios.get` and the one returned by `getStatus`.

Answer (score 0):

No you don’t have to. The async function executes and waits until it returns error or completes execution and return a response!